# Same OS required on machines for home sharing on iTunes?

Tags: itunes

Do both computers need to be running the same operating system for home sharing on iTunes? i.e. do both have to be windows or mac?

Answer (score 1):

No, I believe that Itunes itself installs the required components needed for home sharing.

If you are talking from Itunes on a Mac to Itunes on Windows, it should not be a problem.

Comment: I would rather say that don't have to, but that it helps.